# Change Time Dependent Workflow Action Date

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

Our system is setup to fire emails 60 days before a policy record expires. I simply want to change 60 days to 40 days however I cannot see where the value is defined.

In Workflows & Approvals > Workflow Rules > [entry] > Workflow Actions > Edit > [task] > Edit I have the follow:

[image: example]

"Due date" is "rule trigger date" +1 days however I cannot find where the "rule trigger date" is defined. It should be policy end date -60 days or such.

Any ideas / suggestions appreciated!

Comment: In workflow Actions you did not find anything related to email action.

Answer (score 1):

The 'rule trigger date' is defined in the Workflow Rule criteria. You can view those a little further down the screen in the section 'Rules using this field update'.

Then in the 'Rule Criteria' field you will see some criteria. The moment those are met is the 'Rule Trigger Date'.

Answer (score 0):

> For this why don't you create a workflow rule on Policy Object with a rule criteria on  policy endDate field or some other formula field with value (enddate-60) .
>
> And then simply add a workflow Action '**New Email Alert**' and just pass the email address in Recipient Type.